# Pre Commit Hook for JSLint in Mercurial and Git

Tags: git, mercurial, jslint, pre-commit-hook

I want to run JSLint before a commit into either a Mercurial or Git repo is done.

I want this as an automatic step that is set up instead of relying on the developer (mainly me) remembering to run JSLint before-hand. I normally run JSLint while developing, but want to specify a contract on JS files that they pass JSLint before being committed to the repo.

For Mercurial, [this page](http://hgbook.red-bean.com/read/handling-repository-events-with-hooks.html#sec:hook:precommit) spells out the precommit syntax, but the only variables that seem to be available are the parent1 and parent2 changeset IDs involved in the commit. What I really want are a list of file names that are involved with the commit, so that I can then choose the .js file and run jslint over them.

[Similar issue for GIT](http://book.git-scm.com/5_git_hooks.html), the default info available as part of the precommit script seems limited.

What might work is calling hg status/git status as part of the precommit script, parse that output to find JS files then do the work that way. I was hoping for something easier though, and I am not sure if calling status as part of a precommit hook reflect the correct information. For instance in Git if the changes files have not been added yet, but the git commit uses -a, would the files show up in the correct section of the git status output as being part of the commit set?

**Update**: I got something working, it is visible here: http://github.com/jrburke/dvcs_jslint/

Comment: Just for completeness, here are some instructions for setting up [JSLint as a Subversion Commit Hook](http://www.amaxus.com/cms-blog/jslint-as-subversion-hook).

Comment: Had the same need so I wrote this http://bitbucket.org/robmadole/hgjslint/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For git, there are examples in the .git/hooks directory.  If you just need the file names for JSLint, you could use `git diff --name-only`, which in my example will list the names of the files that differ from the current `HEAD`.

Comment: Thanks for the hint on the git command. So it still seems that I'll need to use a dvcs command to get the list of files and parse out the files to feed to jslint. At least git diff --name-only will make parsing fairly easy.

Answer (score 12):

The following is a variation of @Bitbieger's Git solution that works with [Node.js](http://nodejs.org) and a local copy of [node-jslint](https://github.com/reid/node-jslint) (i.e. you need to `npm install jslint` in your root repository directory).

Additionally the script:

- Runs jslint over all .html and .json files as well as .js
- Only runs jslint over files that have been added, copied or modified. This prevents jslint from erroring on files that have been renamed or deleted.
- Replicates any jslint errors for the user to see
- Uses the `--indent 4 --white true` jslint options to ensure source code consistency

To get it to work copy the following to `.git/hooks/pre-commit` and don't forget to `chmod +x .git/hooks/pre-commit`

```
# Pre-commit hook passing files through jslint
#
# This ensures that all js, html and json files are valid and conform
# to expectations.

ROOT_DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
JSLINT="${ROOT_DIR}/node_modules/.bin/jslint --indent 4 --white true"

for file in $(git diff-index --name-only --diff-filter=ACM --cached HEAD -- | grep -P '\.((js)|(html)|(json))$'); do
    if node $JSLINT $file 2>&1 | grep 'No errors found' ; then
        echo "jslint passed ${file}"
        exit 0
    else
        node $JSLINT $file
        exit 1
    fi  
done
```

Comment: should the "exit 0" be outside the loop? That way the loop will actually check each file, instead of returning on the first one that passed.

Comment: I get the following trying to use this `grep: invalid option -- P
Usage: grep [OPTION]... PATTERN [FILE]...
Try 'grep --help' for more information.` any ideas? I am not familiar with grep but `-P` does appear to be a valid [option](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep).

Answer (score 1):

[JSLint with SpiderMonkey](http://technotales.wordpress.com/2009/06/21/jslint-with-spidermonkey/)

```
for js in $(git diff-index --name-only --cached HEAD -- | grep '\.js$'); do
    if jslint.sh $js 2>&1 | grep 'Lint at line' ; then
        echo $js
        exit 1
    else
        echo "js files validated"
        exit 0
    fi  
done
```