# How to force a code style for a project?

Tags: javascript, node.js, jslint

I'm currently starting to learn about JavaScript on the server side with node, I've created a project with NPM, implemented some tests, etc.

Something that's bugging me is the ability to force a code style on all files, I've been reading about JSLint and it warns you about the style errors, but I'm looking for a tool that modifies your code to obey a certain standard.

Is there any tool that covers this task?

**EDIT**

I'm looking for a command line tool, so I can add a task to the project using NPM and I can execute it as:

```
npm format
```

Comment: Are you looking for an editor that helps suggest what you should do or something that will actually modify your code?

Comment: I prefer a command line tool, but I wouldn't mind if it's embedded on the editor, I'm currently using VIM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to have a look at something like https://github.com/wbecker/dvcs_hook-jslint-node (and [Pre Commit Hook for JSLint in Mercurial and Git](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1837681/pre-commit-hook-for-jslint-in-mercurial-and-git)) which allows you to run jslint with node, and if you are using a compatible versioning system it may do so on each commit (which is a great way to ensure every file respect your coding standard).

Comment: I'm currently using GIT as my code repository so I do consider this as an option.
It seems it just shows warnings and avoids the commit instead of modifying your code.

Comment: Oh my bad then, I didn't get you wanted this tool to actually modify the source... But are you *sure* you want it to behave that way? This may introduce hard to diagnose bugs in the process (e.g. auto adding a semicolon... :s), and I would rather show the error to the committer so he can change it and actually learn your coding standard.

Comment: Yeah, feels like everybody uses jslint or jshint embedded into their ide and correct the error one by one. Guess there is a reason to it ^^, I tend to be too lazy :P